# AngularJs Button : Use expression for value attribute

Tags: angularjs, expression

```
<input type="button" value="
```

> {{ flag ? "Active" : "De-active" }}

```
" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="someFunction()"/>
```

I want above expression to be executed to select the value of value attribute. How can I do that in angularJs? Is there any directive for that?

flag is a boolean value here. Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the following

```
 <input type="button" ng-value="flag ? 'Active' : 'De-active'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="someFunction()"/>
```

And set the flag as `$scope.flag = true` in your controller.

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/12/) for demonstrating.

Comment: it works... I also tried value="flag ? 'Active' : 'De-active'" , and that works fine too.. thanks